# I have a problem with Vlookup with my practice file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have this problem with Vlookup which is already getting on my nerve, I cannot find any generic problems that are the same as mine. Anyways, Vlookup seems not to give out any value or even errors, it just sits there like a text; like this - `VLOOKUP(F2,'Reference Table'!$E$1:$H$37,2,0)`

Even if I drag this formula down it just copies the formula as a text.

Comment: Because you didn't put the `=`?

Comment: Make sure the column you are pasting this into is formatted as "General" - if the cells are formatted as "Text" then even with the `=` it will still be text.

Answer (score 0):

I have literally no clue what you are talking about: I have "copy-pasted" your formula, added a <kbd>=</kbd> character in front of it, and this is what I get:

[image]

For your information, the `Reference Table` sheet looks as follows:

[image]

Can you edit your question and add some screenshots?